# Laravel dependent two dropdown

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, select, foreach, dropdown

[image: table1]

here is my table1 and

[image: table2]

here is my table 2 where table1.id = table2.catid

Now in product entry view, I need two dropdowns selection. Second one is dependent from first one. When I select category named shoes from first drop down, available options would be female, male, infant shoes option in second dropdown. How can I do that in laravel 5.7? Do I need ajax? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Yes You should need Ajax by on change event of select option of category.
- In script tag
  $(document).on("change", ".cat_id", function () {

  ```
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{{route('subcate.select')}}",
                   data: {
                       '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                       'cat_id': $('.cat_id').val()
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                       $(".subcat_id").html("");
                       console.log(data);
                       $(".subcat_id").html(data);

                   }
               });
           });
  ```
- In Controller File
- public function select(Request $request){

  ```
  $subcategories= Subcategory::where('cat_id',$request->cat_id)->get();
  $html='<option value="">Select SubCategory</option>';
  foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
      $html.="<option value='" . $subcategory->id . "'>" . $subcategory->name . "</option>";
  }
  echo $html;
  ```

  }